# Can't fork process: Resource temporarily unavailable issue

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra

I've got a problems with using terminal on macOS 10.12.3 on Mac mini

When I try to run any command I get the following message:

```
can't fork process: Resource temporarily unavailable.
```

I have already had such problem. Last time I was able to fix it - increase the number of process and my system looked like:

```
sysctl -a | grep maxproc  
kern.maxproc: 2048  
kern.maxprocperuid: 2048  


ulimit -a  
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0  
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited  
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited  
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited  
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited  
open files                      (-n) 65536  
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1  
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192  
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited  
max user processes              (-u) 2048  
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

I thought that the problem was solved, but now I had that issue once again.

I was able to solve this problem this time with reboot - but it's strongly undesireable to reboot my mac every time.

Do you have any advise how to fix that problem once and for all?

Answer (score 8):

No idea why your question was downvoted…

---

`sudo sysctl kern.tty.ptmx_max=255` (or 511, or whatever) should fix it.

My default (in El Capitan) was 127. (As a tmux user, I need
more than that.)

To learn more:

```
sysctl -a | grep max
ulimit -a
launchctl limit

cat /private/etc/launchd.conf
cat /private/etc/sysctl.conf

man 8 sysctl
```

Comment: sysctl | grep max  doesn't work :(
usage: sysctl [-bdehiNnoqx] name[=value] ...
       sysctl [-bdehNnoqx] -a

Comment: `kern.tty.ptmx_max: 511` is already set to 511. how much max value can i use?

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting solves the issue. In my case, I opened Activity Monitor and found way too many processes for "Outlook WebContent". I quit MS Outlook and voila, the terminal reopened and that error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience and it turned out I had a cronjob spawning every minute and not finishing.  If you can free up enough resources to run the below command, you can see what is repeatedly spawning.

```
ps -e | awk '{print $4" "$5" "$6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

For me the last few lines were this:

```
  15 /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome
  36 (find)  
1184 (bash)  
1220 (cron)  
1221 /usr/sbin/cron
```

My answer was easy.  `crontab -e` and remove the offending line.  Then a reboot cleared all the zombie crons.

Answer (score 1):

A short-term solution (besides rebooting) is to quit unused apps or close unused documents or projects.